# SQL: Unexpected results with SUM and COUNT functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

bearing in mind the concept of 'RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW', I have used the SUM and COUNT functions as seen in the code, If you look at my results, under TotalSalary I expected 1000 for the first row, second row appears to be correct i.e. 1000 + 1000 = 2000, third row is again incorrect i.e. 1000 + 1000 + 2000 should be 4000 but its 6000, you get the idea, similarly count appears to be giving incorrect results as well, i expected, 1,2,3,4,5,6 ..

```
DECLARE @Employees TABLE
(   EmpId INT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    EmpName VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    EmpGender VARCHAR(10),
    EmpSalary INT
);

INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES ('Rehan','Male', 2000 );
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES ('Rohan','Male', 3000 );
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES ('Donna','Female', 2500 );
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES ('Mark','Male', 1000);
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES ('Aarav','Female', 1000);
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES ('Nick','Male', 2000);

SELECT 
    EmpId, EmpName, EmpGender, EmpSalary
    , SUM(EmpSalary) OVER (ORDER BY EmpSalary) 'TotalSalary'
    , COUNT(EmpSalary) OVER (ORDER BY EmpSalary) 'Count'
FROM @Employees;
```

[image: Results]

Comment: What is the expected results?

Comment: @Sami - It says in the question `i expected, 1,2,3,4,5,6 ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` as the default is `RANGE`.

So

```
SELECT 
    EmpId, EmpName, EmpGender, EmpSalary
    , SUM(EmpSalary) OVER (ORDER BY EmpSalary ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 'TotalSalary'
    , COUNT(EmpSalary) OVER (ORDER BY EmpSalary ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 'Count'
FROM @Employees;
```

Returns something like

```
+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------+
| EmpId | EmpName | EmpGender | EmpSalary | TotalSalary | Count |
+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------+
|     4 | Mark    | Male      |      1000 |        1000 |     1 |
|     5 | Aarav   | Female    |      1000 |        2000 |     2 |
|     6 | Nick    | Male      |      2000 |        4000 |     3 |
|     1 | Rehan   | Male      |      2000 |        6000 |     4 |
|     3 | Donna   | Female    |      2500 |        8500 |     5 |
|     2 | Rohan   | Male      |      3000 |       11500 |     6 |
+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------+
```

It is arbitrary which row comes first in the event of tied `EmpSalary`

[This article](https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/01/22/sql-server-windowing-functions-rows-vs-range/) has more details on `ROWS` vs `RANGE`